# How to create a Custom Image Button, made of three individual buttons and add event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, imagebutton

I want to make a `Custom Image Button` which should be consist of three buttons with attached `click event`.

I tried to make a `Customize button` but I couldn't able attached a separate `event handler`.

 for each button:

```
 class MulitButtons : UserControl
    {
        public Color bckColor1 = Color.Blue;       

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e); 

            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics; 
            RectangleF recF1 = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 40);
            RectangleF recF2 = new RectangleF(100, 0, 100, 40);
            RectangleF recF3 = new RectangleF(200, 0, 100, 40);   
            RectangleF[] arrRecF = { recF1, recF2, recF3 };  

            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            int fontHeight = 10;
            Font font = new Font("Arial", fontHeight);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(bckColor1);    
            SolidBrush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);  

            graphics.DrawRectangles(pen, arrRecF);
            graphics.DrawString(Text, font, textBrush, 10, 10);     
        }

    }
```

Adding event handler:

```
 MulitButtons objMltBtn = new MulitButtons();
 EventHandler handler= new EventHandler(but1_Click);
 objMltBtn.Click += handler;
```

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the requirement?

Comment: For that you have to create one user control which contain the three button each has it's own click event

Comment: Dear @RezaAghaei, I need a custom Image button with Three sections  and on each section click i want to invoke an event which will perform some operation.

Comment: You can simply put 3 buttons side by side and use `Click` event of them. Also as mentioned by Dhaval Patel, if you need to reuse such structure,  you can create a user control containing those 3 buttons, and raise an event when each button clicks and handle those events on your form.

Comment: Dear @RezaAghaei  Well, that's nice suggestion I have to put this button ( which will be consisted of three buttons) in a GridViewColumn and on each button click I have to perform some operations.

Comment: For `DataGridView` the solution is different, its better to use 3 DataGridViewButtonColumn.

Comment: Dear @RezaAghaei I have to use only one `GridViewColumn`, this is constraint.

Comment: Oky sir,Thanks. I will try to implement on your suggestion. @DhavalPatel

Comment: @ImranKhanHunzai: for that you can use CellTemplate

Comment: @ImranKhanHunzai If you want to show a user control in a cell, you should know you can't do it using custom column, custom columns can show custom controls only in edit mode. In view mode you should paint the custom control.

Comment: @ImranKhanHunzai any way, you may find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32281605/3110834) helpful. In the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32281605/3110834) I show a user control in all cells of a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to publish the `Click` events of your inner buttons.

**Solution 1**

This simply publishes the inner click event.

```
public event EventHandler Button1Click
{
    add { button1.Click += value; }
    remove { button1.Click -= value; }
}
```

**Solution 2**

If you want some control over the invoking, do it like this:

```
public MultiButtons()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    button1.Click += ButtonClick;
    button2.Click += ButtonClick;
    button3.Click += ButtonClick;
}

// this handles all of your clicks
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == button1)
        OnButton1Click(EventArgs.Empty);
    // TODO: the other buttons...
}

public event EventHandler Button1Click;

protected virtual void OnButton1Click(EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = Button1Click;        
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
    else
        // you can call some default action if there is no event subscription
        DefaultButton1Click();
}
```

**Update:** I have just seen your comment:

> I need a custom Image button with Three sections and on each section click i want to invoke an event which will perform some operation.

Just create three separate buttons next to each other and draw them in the `Paint` as if they were a single button. Then you can use one of the solutions above.

Comment: Ok sir! @taffer Thanks a lot. I will try to implement your idea.