# Bind list to user control (textbox having button within it) in datagrid c# .net winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have customized data grid in winforms. Each cell is modified with user control (textbox having button within it). I want to assign list values to datagrid. How to do?

Here I can't use

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Source", typeof(string));

foreach (var item in List)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = item.toString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

or

```
dataGridView.DataSource = List;
```

Because it will not reflect in textbox of the datagrid cell. The problem here is with textbox and button embedded within gridview cell.

Additional info:

```
this.Source = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
this.Source.Name = "Source";
this.Source.Width = 350;
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Source);

this.txtbtnControl = new TextBoxButtonControl();
this.txtbtnControl.Visible = false;
this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(this.txtbtnControl);

public class TextBoxButtonControl : UserControl
{
    public TextBox txtCode;
    public Button btnCode;

    public TextBoxButtonControl()
    {
        this.txtCode = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(this.txtCode);
        this.btnCode = new Button();
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnCode);
        this.renderControl();
    }
    public void renderControl()
    {
        this.txtCode.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.txtCode.Width = this.Width + 115;
        this.txtCode.Height = this.Height;
        this.btnCode.Location = new Point(this.Width + 115, 0);
        this.btnCode.Width = 32;
        this.btnCode.Height = 21;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you only put your user control above the cells, while you should create a new `DataGridViewColumn` type and use it.

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei, I have updated question. I have cutomized usercontrol and embedded into cell of datagrid.

Comment: The correct way is creating a custom `DataGridViewColumn`. This way you are only positioning an instance of your control above a cell. You even didn't pass the value of a cell to it.

Comment: Hi Reza Aghaei, I have searched many forums, most of those provide this kind of implementation only. Could you guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Chandra, you can take a look at this [msdn sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Also if you want to cintinue your way, you can take a look at my answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32280673/3110834).

Comment: Thanks Reza Aghaei, Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in List)
{
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
}
```

Above is solution (sample) for the problem for 1 column in datagrid view.

```
foreach (var item in List)
{
string temp = "Get 2nd variable value";
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item, temp);
}
```

Above is the solution (sample) for the 2 columns in datagrid view.

Thanks for all your support.