# Creating a customized DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently using WinForms in C# to create a customized `DataGridView`.
The results I wanted was to have multiple checkboxes displayed horizontally in one column. There will be information featuring in the other columns as well.

```
Column 1| Column 2            |Column 3 
data    | checkbox1 checkbox2 | data 
data    | checkbox1 checkbox2 | data
```

The answers suggested that I rather use `ListView` instead. The problem with `ListView` is that it will also add checkboxes in other columns as well, instead of adding checkboxes in one column.
Are there other ways to create the customized view as shown above?

Code:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { 
    new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), 
    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), 
    new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) 
}); 
dt.Rows.Add(1, "Triston", "France"); 
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Parkiston", "Russia"); 
CheckedListBoxColumn checkbox = new CheckedListBoxColumn(); dt.Columns.Add(checkbox); 
GridView1.DataSource = dt; 
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: can you use dataTable ?

Comment: I am using datatable but it is still not working

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                            new DataColumn("Country",typeof(string)) });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "Triston", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Parkiston", "Russia");
        CheckedListBoxColumn checkbox = new CheckedListBoxColumn();
        dt.Columns.Add(checkbox);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: I need it to display just like the one above

Comment: Really GridView? __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Also please add the code to the question, not a comment! - Since __one Cell__ can only have __one value__ your task is certainly not well supported, to say the least..You can host a usercontrol with two checkboxes, though, if you really really want it.. Lot of work for little effect. I think I'd rather owner-draw the header of two separate cells to fake a span.

Comment: Ok..I'll take note! Is there any examples for the host a usercontrol? And also what does it mean to owner-draw the header two separate cells to fake a span.

Comment: Think about requirements and available options and choose the solution. This post is also an option: [How to add a UserControl to a DataGridView in VB.net, and have the control always showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280673/how-to-add-a-usercontrol-to-a-datagridview-in-vb-net-and-have-the-control-alway)

Comment: By the way, the codes which you shared are not working.

Comment: Google is your friend: [How to host a control?](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+datagridview+host+a+control&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) - [how to owner-draw a DGV header](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+datagridview+host+a+control&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=c%23+datagridview+owner-draw+header) - You still should try to explain just why y<ou think you need those two checkboxes and in the same column!? Do your names constis ok two bools??? Mrs True-True from India ;-?